# What phase of an electromagnetic wave is the ground state?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, ground-state

I have read that the uncertainty principle applies to electromagnetic radiation, and the ground state could not be sitting on the lowest energy point, because then it would have definite position and velocity. (The universe in a nutshell - Stephen Hawking). What phase of the wave is the ground state?

Comment: What do you mean by "phase"?

Comment: Slightly off-topic:  despite his brilliance, Hawking has written some very questionable things in his popular works.   Don't take everything in his books as gospel.  I can't comment on this particular one, however, because I don't have the text.